# Create documentation for ionic app using gulp

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to generate documentation for my ionic mobile app. I have gulpfile.js in my project. After looking online I came across following options:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-jsdoc
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-jsdoc

I have followed the instructions and updated my gulpfile.js as required but nothing happened. Can someone guide me step by step about how to generate documentation. Also if generated, where it gets saved? I am very new to gulp and ionic. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code of your implementation

Comment: https://github.com/pritpalchahal/flax-related-words

Comment: edit your question and add your code please